# Background Colour Change by Timer

Tags: android, timer, setbackground

```
public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvTimer.setText("timer=" + String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                    TimeCounter++;
                    A.setBackgroundColor(123455+TimeCounter*100000);
                }

               });
            }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

---

I have created a timer that his role to count the running time of the application, and i want to change the background color as long as the timer goes up. what is wrong with my script?

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working?

Comment: the timer is working fine, the seconds going up but the background ins't changing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the value that you are passing to the `setBackgroundColor` method.

From the doc of the class [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) we can see that:

> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) |
>   (green << 8) | blue.

In your code, the first value that you are passing (supposing the `TimeCounter` starts from 0) is `123455` which corresponds to `0x0001E23F` in hexadecimal.

By decomposing it, we have:

```
alpha=0x00
red=0x01
green=0xE2
blue=0x3F
```

It gives you 0% for the alpha value which means that the color is **transparent**.

You are adding `100000` to this value every second. So it will take you about 166 seconds (almost 3 minutes) to have a color with an alpha value greater than 0 (but it will still be invisble as the percentage of alpha will be lower than 1%).

To fix it, you can use an offset to each color to set the alpha value to 100%. For that you just have to add `0xff000000 (4 278 190 080)` to the color value.

Finally, just be sure that the color value is always lower than the maximum value `0xffffffff (4 294 967 295)` and it should work.

Here is a sample code:

```
private int offsetColor = 0xFF000000; //offset to have 100% in alpha value
public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvTimer.setText("timer=" + String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                    TimeCounter++;
                    if (TimeCounter < 167) {
                        A.setBackgroundColor(offsetColor+TimeCounter*100000);
                    } else {
                        /* You just reach the limit: 0xFFFFFFFF which is White */
                    }
                }
           });
        }
}, 0, 1000);
```

With this example you can do 166 iterations (166 seconds). You can change the value that you are adding each second to adjust the duration of your animation.

Comment: well thank you very much for the help, there is no error at Eclipse but it doesn't work.. Im getting a permanent gray background..

Comment: Are you sure it is a permanent color or is it changing very slowly?

Comment: Are you testing it on the emulator? It can be the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the color code set in the  **A.setBackgroundColor();**

I have simple and logical solution of this:
1.make color array like this

```
int[] colors=new int[]{Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.RED,Color.YELLOW};
   int i=0;
```

1. set color of array by its index as i increments in Runnable:

   ```
      public void run() {

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

               public void run() {

                   tvTimer.setText("timer=" + String.valueOf(TimeCounter));

                   TimeCounter++;

                   A.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);

                   i++;
                   if(i==5){
                   i=0;
                   }
               }

              });
           }
   }, 0, 1000);
   ```

Comment: hello,well your solution did work, but i want to see a development as long as the timer goes up, for example if the it will start with red, as the timer goes up the red will be darker.. your solution changed my color from red to blue by one second.

Answer (score 0):

See I have create new application for your color change as you required.:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView iv;

int red = 255, green = 0, blue = 0;
int i = 0;
int a = 30;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // m.postScale(2f, 2f);
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a, red, green, blue));
                    Log.d("main", "i: " + i + " a:+ " + a + " red: " + red
                            + " green: " + green + " Blue: " + blue);
                    a = a + 30;
                    // set 30 to 60 for more difference
                    if (a > 250) {
                        a = 30;
                        i++;
                        if (i == 1) {
                            red = 0;
                            green = 255;
                            blue = 0;
                        } else if (i == 2) {
                            red = 0;
                            green = 0;
                            blue = 255;

                        } else if (i == 3) {
                            red = 255;
                            green = 0;
                            blue = 0;

                        }

                        if (i == 3) {
                            i = 1;
                        }

                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
}
```

Now Enjoy Good Luck ..